# Understanding promql grafana output

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am trying out django dashboards for grafana. I imported a dashbord from grafana.com. Below is how the dashboard renders the volume of 3xx and 5xx reponses:

[image]

Why 3XX shows N/A while 5XX shows 0.00req/s when query for them exactly same?

Query for 3XX:

```
sum(irate(django_http_responses_total_by_status_total{status=~"3.+",
    app=~"^$application$"}[$__rate_interval]))
```

Query for 5XX:

```
sum(irate(django_http_responses_total_by_status_total{status=~"5.+",
    app=~"^$application$"}[$__rate_interval]))
```

Is it because there was some 5XX response, but not in selected time range, but there was never a 3XX response?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because there was some 5XX response, but not in selected time range, but there was never a 3XX response?

Yes.

`3XX` query hadn't returned any results, so Grafans shows `N/A`. You can overrule what is show when query doesn't return anything with Dashboard option "No value".

---

Side note: regex selectors in Prometheus expected to match full value of the label, so `^` and `$` are redundant in this selector: `app=~"^$application$"`